# Rsync copy some, exclude the rest

Tags: rsync

So I need to copy a bunch of files from a directory but exclude the rest, my attemp was:

```
rsync --include-from=list-of-included-files.txt --exclude=* src/dir dest
```

and also tried another rsync options. but still doesnt work, it still copy whole files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Now having a better understanding of what you want, you could try this:

```
rsync --include-from='include.txt' --exclude-from='exclude.txt' src/dir dtest
```

where the exclude.txt contains a list of all files in the directory.

Your original code doesn't work as `rsync` seems to require the `--include` argument before the`--exclude` likewise with  `--include-from` and `--exclude-from`. So if in your original code instead you used `--include` and not `--include-from` that would have also worked.

Old:

I think what you're looking for is the `--exclude-from` option, which takes a list of excluded files in a text file like so:

```
rsync --exclude-from='exclude.txt' src/dir dtest
```

Comment: thanks @LRP, but the number of excluded files is too huge to be listed one by one in a file.

Comment: Answer is now updated. Let me know if this works for you